# Python logic to compare two files iteratively and build parent child relation

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Could someone please help me with a simpler logic? I have been scratching my head for 2 days.

Problem: - I have two CSV files. Trying to establish a parent/child relationship until the relation gets exhausted b/w the two files.

> Assume, both the files have 2 columns  A, B in 1st csv and C, D in second CSV.
>
> "A" should be matched with "C" and for the matching rows [Inner Join], take the "D" and compare it with "B" [Again an inner join]. Then again, from the result, A should be matched against "C" till the relation or chain stops somewhere.

Basically, in my problem B is the child of D and B by itself might have another Child.

Not sure I am making it clear

Thanks for offering to help. I have created the dummy data.    Please see if it helps

Input data in two csv files as below

```
A   B            C    D
310 9000        310 8000                                                                         
320 8000        320 2000   
330 2000        330 1000
340 1000        350 2500
```

Expected output in new file or dataframe:- Chain stops at 1000 as 340 doesn't have row in second csv.

Expected output data:-

```
    A   B    C   D    E   F
1. 310 8000 320 2000 330 1000
```

Comment: Can someone please help me with it?

Comment: Hi Karthik. Welcome to Stackoverlfow :) Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then make the required changes to your question.

Comment: HI Mohit, thanks for looking into my question. Think I made the question little better.

Comment: can you show an example of what you have tried?

Comment: Can you add some dummy data, so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Thanks, I have added the dummy data to my question. Pleas let me know if anything required

Comment: Is that your expected output or original data which you want to process? If one of these, then add the other too.

Comment: Thats the original data and have added the expected output as well to the question

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, I think this is what you need:

```
df1

    A   B
0   310 9000
1   320 8000
2   330 2000

df2

     C  D
0   310 8000
1   320 2000
2   330 1000
```

Merge the dfs:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = ['A'], right_on = ['C'])
merged_df
     A   B       C  D
0   310 9000    310 8000
1   320 8000    320 2000
2   330 2000    330 1000
```

Assuming that D is child of B when B>D:

```
result = merged_df.loc[merged_df['B']>merged_df['D'],['C', 'D']].values.ravel()
result
array([ 310, 8000,  320, 2000,  330, 1000], dtype=int64)
```

Convert them to a series:

```
pd.Series(result, index = list('ABCDEF'))
A     310
B    8000
C     320
D    2000
E     330
F    1000
```

Comment: Thanks, Mohit for taking time to help me out. But in my scenario, the column C and D can also have alphanumeric characters. Also, I will have "n" number of parent/child relations like we see in the output

Comment: oh, I see. You should mention all cases in your question. It's easier to understand with the relevant data.

Comment: Yeah, should have that. Sorry about that, I missed that part

Comment: Could someone help me on this?